# flowtype plugin affects other parts of code

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I am integrating a package with flowtype for the purpose of that in my webpack file added dependency to webpack as follows

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        // exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: [
              ["@babel/preset-env"],
              ["@babel/preset-react"],

              [
                require.resolve("babel-preset-react-app/dependencies"),
                { helpers: true },
              ],
            ],
            plugins: [
              [
                "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                {
                  loose: true,
                },
              ],
              ["transform-flow-strip-types"],
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

now all the flow type errors have been solved but many other new errors are introduced like

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
```

in import statements where the statement is like

```
import Button from './Libraries/Components/Button';
```

any idea on what might be causing these issues ?

Comment: Is that an error from webpack, from flow, or from runtime JS? Does that module exist in the place you would expect? Was the import statement changed as part of the move to flow?

Comment: Can you please provide more info. This could very well be a flow error, but to help us narrow it down. Did this error start coming up after you added `// @flow`? What is the exact path you are trying to import, is it really relative or is it like `'components/Button'` because this could be related to module resolution or flow-typed